# Understanding routes' method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am new to rails and quite lost in understanding some code from a project I am working on :

In `routes.rb`, I have

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
...

  map.filter "repository_owner_namespacing", :file => "route_filters/repository_owner_namespacing"
...
end
```

I try to understand how a method `around_recognize` is called in `repository_owner_namespacing.rb` . The latter file begins as so

```
require 'routing_filter/base'

module RoutingFilter
  class RepositoryOwnerNamespacing < Base
...
def around_recognize
...
```

`around_recognize` seems to be called in routing_filter.rb which begins as so :

```
module RoutingFilter
  mattr_accessor :active
  @@active = true

  class Chain < Array


    def << (filter)
      filter.successor = last
      super
    end

    def run(method, *args, &final)
      RoutingFilter.active ? last.run(method, *args, &final) : final.call
    end
  end
end

# allows to install a filter to the route set by calling: map.filter 'locale'
ActionController::Routing::RouteSet::Mapper.class_eval do
  def filter(name, options = {})
    require options.delete(:file) || "routing_filter/#{name}"
    klass = RoutingFilter.const_get name.to_s.camelize
    @set.filters << klass.new(options)
  end
end
def filters
    @filters ||= RoutingFilter::Chain.new
end
```

...

and routoing_fiter/base.rb, there is

```
module RoutingFilter
  class Base
    attr_accessor :successor, :options

    def initialize(options)
      @options = options
      options.each{|name, value| instance_variable_set :"@#{name}", value }
    end

    def run(method, *args, &block)
      successor = @successor ? lambda { @successor.run(method, *args, &block) } : block
      send method, *args, &successor
    end
  end
end
```

My problem is that I really don't know where 'last' is set (in `filter.successor = last`), and where @set is set. I can't find any comprehensive trace from them in the code's project. Does it correspond to ruby or rails built-in variables ? (Btw, what does this  `@set.filters << klass.new(options)` corresponds to ?)

Answer (score 1):

In your code `RoutingFilter::Chain` extends `Array`.  The `last` method is [defined in Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-last) .  So in this case it is the last filter added to the chain.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, does @set.filters << klass.new(options) means that the klass instance has know a successor attribute which is last ??

Comment: the ```klass.new``` will create a new instance.  For example, passing in repository_owner_namespacing creates a new RepositoryOwnerNamespacing instance).  This instance is then appended to the current chain.  Looking at the overridden << operation, we first grap the current last element and add it to the newly added filter as the successor.  Then we append the filter to the end of the list.

Comment: I am so sorry, all this seems tricky to me : does << in '@set.filters << klass.new(options)' refers to the chain's method << ? What does mean appending a class to another class ? what does @set refers to ? Does 'filter.successor = last' means that we add last method to the RepositoryOwnerNamespacing instance ? If yes, how does it come because  this instance is not an array object ?

Comment: Yes, ```<<``` is defined in ```Chain```.  It is also defined in ```Chain```'s super class ```Array````, thus the call to ```super```.  The ```@set``` is the route set object.  The ```Chain``` *is* an ```Array```, ```Array``` is the parent.